# Using Array Notation Or Pointer Arithmetic to Get Last Five Values Of Array In C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper array notation for the
program in order to return the last five values of array "prime".

In other words I want the highest five values of the array as it's set to calculate prime numbers in ascending order from one to one thousand.

Originally this question asked about the correct pointer notation for array

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000

int is_prime(int n);
int maximum(int array[], int i);


int main(){
  int n;
  int prime[ARRAY_SIZE];
  int k=0;
  for(n = 0; k < ARRAY_SIZE; ++n){
    if(is_prime(n)){
      prime[k] = n;
      printf("%d\n", prime[k]);
      k++;
    }
  }
  maximum(prime, k);

}

int maximum(int array[], int k){
  int i;
  int max = array[0];
  second_largest;
  for(i = 1; i < k; i++)
    if(array[i] > max)
      max = array[i];
  second_largest = array[k-2];
  printf("largest element = %d\n", max);
  printf("second largest element = %d", array[k-2];
}


int is_prime(int n)
{
  for (int d = 2; d < n; ++d)
    if(n%d == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `is_prime` will return 1 for both `0` and `1`, neither of which is considered prime.

Comment: Also, the loop in `main` sets `prime[k]`, but `k` is a constant `0` throughout that loop.  So all it's doing is setting `prime[0]` to the last prime it finds.  Then, when it calls `maximum`, it's passing `0` for `k`.  That doesn't seem to be what you want.  You probably want to increment `k` each time you store a new value.

Comment: Be aware that correct type for passing array sizes is `size_t`, *not* `int`.

Comment: You say you have tried “something” along certain lines but do not show us the actual code. Nowhere in the code you show is there any attempt to access the array by some number of elements from its end. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Your `main` routine never increments `k`, so it never writes any element of `prime` other than `prime[0]`. If you attempt to go back 1, 2, 3, or 4 elements from that, you will access the array out of bounds. That can produce the “seemingly random integers” you report—the behavior is not defined by the C standard. So you have likely drawn a wrong conclusion—the “seemingly random integers” are not caused by incorrectly calculating the locations of the desired elements but by the fact your code never writes enough elements to go back from.

Comment: Additionally, your loop runs until `n < ARRYSIZE` is false, so it tests `ARRYSIZE` numbers for primality. That does not mean it finds `ARRYSIZE` primes. It will find fewer primes than that. Then, to locate the last primes, you need to work backward from the number of primes the code found, not the number of elements in the `primes` array. So any method using the size of the array, including `(int *)(&a+1)-1` and `sizeof(prime)/sizeof(prime[0])-1`, is wrong.

Comment: Also, `(int *)(&a+1)-1` is technically incorrect; its behavior is not properly defined by the C standard. `&a+1` points to where another array following `a` would be, and this is allowed by the C standard, but the behavior of converting it to `int *`, as `(int *)` attempts to do, is not defined. Clang and GCC are increasing doing optimizations based on provenance of pointers, so, even though this conversion looks easy and obvious based on how machine addresses work, it may not survive compiler optimization.

Comment: The correct test to fill the entire array with primes is `k < ARRYSIZE` – and please rename to `ARRAYSIZE`, that single letter doesn't spare you much and the complete name reads better (I personally would even prefer `ARRAY_SIZE`).

Comment: OK, now with your edit you introduced another bug: `k` is left uninitialised and might contain any arbitrary garbage value, reading it results in undefined behaviour!

Comment: @AConcagua sorry i'm pretty new to c programming. Do you mean writing another for loop in the same vein as (n = 0; n < ARRAY_SIZE; ++n)

Comment: Where will your maximum value reside??? As you calculate one prime after another, the last value you calculated *must* be the maximum value as well, so no need to iterate over the array *again*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil whenever i add a statement to increment k such as k++ beneath prime[k] = n I no longer receive values that make any sense. Is this due to array bounds as well?

Comment: @amsdecember No, not another loop. Just modify the loop you have already: `int k = 0; for(int n = 0; k < ARRAY_SIZE; ++n) { /* the loop you have already */ }` – and please don't modify the question in a way that it might invalidate given answers. As soon as an answer is given already, edits should be clearly visible as such (like *'Edit: Changed my code to the following [...]'*, leaving the previous code intact).

Comment: In the three lines `prime[k] = n;`, `k++;`, and `printf("%d\n", prime[k]);`, what do you think `printf` prints for `prime[k]` after `k++` has been executed? At this point, you should spend time debugging your program; there is no question suitable for Stack Overflow here. Change `ARRAY_SIZE` to 5 or so and either single-step through you program in a debugger or insert lots of `printf` statements to show the values of variables at various places, until you see what the program is computing and what it is doing wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil okay thank you for trying.

Comment: Just noticing: *'from one to one thousand'* – do you want to calculate one thousand prime numbers – or all those primes *below* one thousand??? In the *latter* case your original loop (`for(int n = 0; n < ARRAY_SIZE; ++n)`) actually would have been correct – but you wouldn't find the desired five elements at the array end – instead you would find them at `int* lastFive = prime + k - 5;`!

Comment: I'm confused - you know how many prime values are in the array (`k`), you just need to pass that as a separate parameter to any routine that works with the array. You've generated the primes in ascending order, so your max value will be the `k-1`'th value.  The last 5 elements are simply `array[k-5]`, `array[k-4]`, `array[k-3]`, `array[k-2]`, and `array[k-1]`.  If you want a pointer to the start of that sequence, you can obtain it with `&array[k-5]`.  Or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @JohnBode: The code originally in the question never incremented `k`, so accessing `array[k-5]` etc. accessed elements before the array, resulting in “seemingly random integers.” OP never showed the actual code that did that, just partially described it. The question is missing information and should be closed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I need to admit that I added confusion myself due to possibly misinterpreting *'from one to one thousand'* in the context *'the last five array elements'* (see my previous comment). Sorry for.

Comment: think i just solved it

Comment: @JohnBode it doesnt require pointers at all. arrray notation ie. "The last 5 elements are simply array[k-5], array[k-4], array[k-3], array[k-2], and array[k-1]. If you want a pointer to the start of that sequence, you can obtain it with &array[k-5]." alongside adding incrementation of k seemed to have fixed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 100

int is_prime(int n);
int maximum(int array[], int i);


int main(){
  int n;
  int prime[ARRAY_SIZE];
  int k = 0;
  for(n = 0; n < ARRAY_SIZE; ++n){
    if(is_prime(n)){
      prime[k] = n;
      printf("%d\n", prime[k]);
      k++;
    }
  }
  maximum(prime, k);
}

int maximum(int array[], int k){
  int i;
  int max = array[0];
  int second_largest;
  int third_largest;
  int fourth_largest;
  int fifth_largest;
  for(i = 1; i < k; i++)
    if(array[i] > max)
      max = array[i];
  second_largest = array[k-2];
  third_largest = array[k-3];
  fourth_largest = array[k-4];
  fifth_largest = array[k-5];
  printf("largest element = %d\n", max);
  printf("second largest element = %d\n", second_largest);
  printf("third largest element  = %d\n", third_largest);
  printf("fourth largest element = %d\n", fourth_largest);
  printf("fifth largest element = %d\n", fifth_largest);
}


int is_prime(int n)
{
  for (int d = 2; d < n; ++d)
    if(n%d == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*'should I be using [...]?'* – Yes, apart from that you should subtract 5, not 1, to get the last five elements.

Be aware that this `sizeof` trick only works as long as you have the array yet available as raw; once decayed to pointer (e. g. when passed to a function) you need to have the size available separately (e. g. passed as additional parameter; but then you get the value for exactly the same way).

The full expression would look like:

```
int* lastFive = a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) - 5;
```

By using a as operand to + it already decays to a pointer; alternatively, if you like better, you could write

```
int* lastFive = &a[sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) -5];
```

Side note 1: When applying the dereferencing operator `*` to `a` in my preferred alternative variant (shorter to type), the array again decays to a pointer automatically – just as actually happens, too, when applying the index operator `[]`, where `a[i]` actually is nothing else than syntactic sugar for `*(a + i)` – which explains why `5[a]` (strange looking isn't it?) actually is valid C and means exactly the same...

Side note 2: Calculating the prime number from scratch again and again is pretty inefficient. At very first: You only need to iterate as long as `k*k` is yet smaller than `n`! If any `k` larger than the square root of `n` divides, then there *must* be another factor smaller than – which you have already found before.

Then you can profit from the fact that you have the previous primes available already; you might re-use the array for calculating the new primes. The calculation might look like

```
for(k = 0; primes[k]*primes[k] < n; ++k)
{
    if(n % primes[k] == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```

Note that as the primes grow faster than indices they will exceed square root of `n` faster and you don't need to check for `k` exceeding number of already calculated primes or the array size.

Side note 3: *'[...] prime numbers in ascending order from one to one thousand.'* – the prime numbers grow faster than the array indices – if you only are interested in prime numbers smaller than one thousand you won't find these at the array end! They will be the last five values calculated:

```
int k = 0;
for(int n = 0; n < ARRAY_SIZE; ++n)
{
    if(is_prime(n)
        prime[k++] = n;
}

int* lastFive = prime + k - 5;
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's rather a bug there. I'll add some lines for.

Comment: OP edited their code, so my comment is stale. In any case, I voted to close due to lack of MRE and likely misdiagnosis of the cause of the observed behavior. The question likely should not be answered until OP provides an MRE or otherwise clarifies the question.